# Разовая аутентификация Scala (PlayFramework) + mobile app

Tags: scala, аутентификация, playframework, authenticationtoken

Есть мобильное приложение, которое при аутентификации запрашивает номер телефона, отправляет код из смс.

Сделал кастомно, посылается запрос на бэк с номером телефона, который в свою очередь формирует запрос к sms сервису. Сервис выдаёт токен, который отправляется при подтверждении кода из смс. В случае успеха, выдаю токен, который живёт определенное время.

Необходимо на `Scala` + `PlayFramework` запилить аутентификацию, например, как в Wats'up, telegram, где токен не протухает.

Я долго ищу информацию, какими библиотеками реализовать подобное, но решение так и не нашел, буду признателен совету.